# I can't get the colorshemes to work in neovim

Tags: 14.04, command-line, neovim

I used neovim in archlinux and colors were working fine, I used rxvt-unicode and zsh. I try to do the same in ubuntu but the colors look like crap. It's dark and not the right colors. Any ideas how to fix this?

`set t_Co=256` is set

`TERM=xterm-256color` is set

`$NVIM_TUI_ENABLE_TRUE_COLOR=1` is set...

The colorscheme I'm trying to make work is molokai. 
And this is what I get...
[image: Like crap]
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had problems with this too - upgrading gnome-terminal is what did it for me.

[How can I upgrade gnome-terminal on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/605986/how-can-i-upgrade-gnome-terminal-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts)

Also, I don't think you'll need t_Co=256 in your init / vimrc.