# Upgrade Ubuntu package from source tarball. Example: gnome-terminal and VTE

Tags: package-management, software-installation, gnome-terminal

I am using Ubuntu 17.04 and I am trying to compile [gnome-terminal](https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-terminal) from source, but `./autogen.sh` complains about `vte`:

```
configure: error: Package requirements (vte-2.91 >= 0.49.2
   glib-2.0 >= 2.42.0
   gio-2.0 >= 2.34.0
   gtk+-3.0 >= 3.12.0
   gsettings-desktop-schemas >= 0.1.0
   dconf >= 0.14.0
   uuid
   libpcre2-8 >= 10.00
    x11) were not met:

Requested 'vte-2.91 >= 0.49.2' but version of vte is 0.44.2
```

I if I check my installation for packages matching `vte`:

```
$ apt list --installed | grep vte
ir1.2-vte-2.91/zesty,now 0.44.2-1ubuntu3 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libvte-2.91-0/zesty,now 0.44.2-1ubuntu3 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libvte-2.91-common/zesty,zesty,now 0.44.2-1ubuntu3 all [installed,automatic]
libvte-2.91-dev/zesty,now 0.44.2-1ubuntu3 amd64 [installed]
libvte-2.91-doc/zesty,zesty,now 0.44.2-1ubuntu3 all [installed,automatic]
libvte-common/zesty,zesty,now 1:0.28.2-5ubuntu3 all [installed,automatic]
libvte-dev/zesty,now 1:0.28.2-5ubuntu3 amd64 [installed]
libvte-doc/zesty,zesty,now 1:0.28.2-5ubuntu3 all [installed,automatic]
libvte9/zesty,now 1:0.28.2-5ubuntu3 amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

and I can see that I have installed version 0.44.2 by querying the package status of `libvte-2.91-dev`:

```
$ dpkg -s libvte-2.91-dev | grep Version
Version: 0.44.2-1ubuntu3
```

Now, I have downloaded the latest version of vte `0.49.2` [from GitHub](https://github.com/GNOME/vte).

How can I proceed to replace the installed version `0.44.2` with the downloaded version `0.49.2` so I can compile `gnome-terminal`? Can I just run (from the VTE source directory):

```
./autogen.sh
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

and it will magically work, or do I need to uninstall the existing version (and also its dependencies) first?

**Edit**:

I chose to install `libvte` to a custom folder instead (using `--prefix` option):

```
$ ./autogen.sh --prefix=/opt/vte --disable-introspection --disable-vala
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

But problem is now that `autogen.sh` in the `gnome-terminal` source directory still does not find the newly installed VTE. I tried running:

```
$ PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/vte ./autogen.sh
[...]
Requested 'vte-2.91 >= 0.49.2' but version of vte is 0.44.2
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: You can try it but you might also break Ubuntu.

Comment: I tried to install `libvte` in a custom folder instead (see my updated question), but it still does not work..

Comment: You need the `-dev` package of each missing dependency installed. Sometimes there's a `lib` prefix, and the numbers might also differ from the ones reported in the error. Use some heuristics and TAB completion after `sudo apt install`. E.g. for `glib-2.0` you'll need to install `libglib2.0-dev`, for `gtk+-3.0` install `libgtk-3-dev`, for `uuid` install `uuid-dev` and so on.

Comment: @egmont Thanks! I managed to find the missing packages, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to compile `gnome-terminal` from source on Ubuntu 17.04. For reference, here is the recipe that worked for me:

- **Install Ubuntu packages**:

  ```
  sudo apt get install \
  intltool libpcre2-dev libdconf-dev uuid-dev libglib2.0-dev \
  libgtk-3-dev libgirepository1.0-dev libvala-0.34-dev valac yelp-tools \
  libnautilus-extension-dev gtk-doc-tools libpcre2-dev libgirepository1.0-dev \
  gnome-common gobject-introspection gsettings-desktop-schemas-dev
  ```
- **Install latest version of VTE** (latest version not available as an Ubuntu package):

  [Download](https://github.com/GNOME/vte) VTE from GitHub, then in the source folder:

  ```
  ./autogen.sh --prefix=/opt/vte
  make
  sudo make install
  ```
- **Install `gnome-terminal`**:

  First [download](https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-terminal) `gnome-terminal` from GitHub, then in the source folder:

  ```
  PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/vte/lib/pkgconfig ./autogen.sh \
  --disable-search-provider --prefix=/opt/gnome-terminal
  ```

  This will install `gnome-terminal` in `/opt/gnome-terminal/bin/gnome-terminal`